# Accessing my node.js by others?

Tags: node.js, webserver

I have successfully launched my *node.js* server, and can access it through `http://localhost:3000`

How do I allow others see my development server? I do not have external IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For quick sharing in development stage there is a special NPM module called [localtunnel](https://www.npmjs.org/package/localtunnel). Do not use this method in production website due to security concerns.

Using localtunnel after you installed it (`npm install -g localtunnel`):

```
lt --port 3000
```

It shall output you the externally accessible URL after running the command, share this url with your friends.